# Is there a good overview of the VOLTTRON platform that describes how it works

Tags: volttron

Is there a good overview of the VOLTTRON platform? What about user and developer documentation?

How can I get to these docs?

Answer (score 2):

A technical overview of the VOLTTRON platform can be found at:
http://bgintegration.pnnl.gov/pdf/PNNL-25499_VOLTTRON_2016.pdf

VOLTTRON developer documentation is at:
http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/